# Input control losing focus after each keystroke

Tags: reactjs, state

I have an object state like this:

```
const [form, setForm] = useState({
  name: '',
  addr: '',
  ...
  })
```

And I use a helper component:

```
const InputField = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form.Control 
        name={props.name}
        type={props.type}
        placeholder={props.label}
        value={form[props.name]}
        onInput = { (e) => {
          setForm( { ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value } ) 
        } }
      />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

I use this like:

```
return (
  ...
  <InputField name="name" type="text" label="Name, Firma:" />
  <InputField name="addr" type="text" label="Adresse:" />
  ...
)
```

Everything works fine, except the input control accepts only one keystroke. Only after I click the input again, it accepts another character. So, it seems, the input looses focus. But why, what's wrong? What can I do against this behavior?

Comment: Not sure if I understand it correctly, but where do `form` and `useForm` come from in your `InputField` component? At the moment, I think this `InputField` is defined inside another component which could cause your issue. Could you post the full code?

Comment: You're right, the helper component <InputField> is inside the main component. This, because else I couldn't use the state 'form' and setForm.

Comment: You can always pass down `props` so it's not really an excuse ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that your `InputField` component is inside another component which re-renders every time you type something and it makes it look like you're losing focus. You need to move it out of there and pass down an `onInput` callback to handle the changes:

```js
function InputField({ label, name, onInput, type, value }) {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form.Control
        name={name}
        onInput={onInput}
        placeholder={label}
        type={type}
        value={value}
      />
    </Container>
  );
}

function ParentComponent() {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({
    name: '',
    addr: '',
  });

  function handleInputChange(e) {
    setForm({ ...form, [e.target.name]: e.target.value });
  }

  return (
    <Form>
      <InputField
        name="name"
        type="text"
        label="Name, Firma:"
        onInput={handleInputChange}
        value={form.name}
      />
      <InputField
        name="addr"
        type="text"
        label="Adresse:"
        onInput={handleInputChange}
        value={form.addr}
      />
    </Form>
  );
}
```

You could also loop through your `state` so you don't have to type every input field manually. And please, please, use `label`s in your forms, don't rely on `placeholder` values. They are there for hints, and they're not accessible. Assistive technology won't announce your inputs properly, and users who rely on such technology won't be able to use your form.

Comment: Thanks a lot, Zsolt, for your prompt answer, I will try this asap. Also thanks for the hint regarding placeholders. I was using this because it takes less space on small forms than extra labels.

Answer (score -1):

try these fixes:-

#### Fixes 1

- should use `onChange` instead of `onInput`
- should just straightaway use `name` than `[e.target.name]` in `onChange` event
- `helper component`:-

```js
const InputField = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Form.Control 
        name={props.name}
        type={props.type}
        placeholder={props.label}
        value={form[props.name]}
        onChange = { (e) => {
          setForm( { ...form, name: e.target.value } ) 
        } }
      />
    </Container>
  )
}
```

You can see this working [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mystifying-visvesvaraya-h6pds?file=/src/App.js) for reference

Comment: This is not correct:
1, both `onChange` and `onInput` are fine to use
2, he has to use `event.target.name` and not just `name` as he's trying to update different properties in `state` and the keys are stored in the `input` fields' `name` attribute

Comment: thanks for the clarification. Appreciated it